# Xcode setImage (image from imagePickerController) not working, but setBackgroundImage is working, any ideas?

Tags: ios, xcode, button, uiimagepickercontroller

The below code is puzzling me as to why it isn't working.
I have commented out the setImage line for the time being and used `setBackgroundImage` instead, but I need `setImage` to work.
Button type is Custom.

```
-(void)customButton1{
    if (customphoto1 == 1) {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; //Get the docs directory
        NSString *filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Buttons1image.png"]; //Add the file name
        UIImage *imageLoaded1 = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


        //below works
        [_button1 setBackgroundImage:imageLoaded1 forState:UIControlStateNormal]
        //below doesn't work?!?! why?
        //[_button1 setImage:imageLoaded1 forState:UIControlStateNormal]
    }
    else {
        button1ImageName = @"addnew";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the button type, if it is system type, change it to custom should work.

Comment: Thanks but as mentioned in my post, button type is already custom

Comment: So what is the result of setting image, do you see any changes to the button appearance?